# Javascript [0] at the end of match statement

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I have the following:

```
    var1 = "www.asite.page.co.uk";
    var2 = '.' + var1.match(/\w*\.\w*$/) [0];
```

I understand that it's trying to achieve ".co.uk", but I have no idea what the [0] does.
Is it error handling?

Answer (score 4):

The match method returns an array of matches, so the [0] gets the first element of that array -- i.e. just the full match.

See the documentation for [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) or [Rob W's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9428633/84619) for a more complete description.

Comment: But note that NULL is returned if the match fails and then the [0] will produce an error. I often use something of the form (x.match(y)||["?"])[0] which will return "?" if the match fails.

Answer (score 4):

[`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) returns an **array** of **strings**.

Without the global flag, the array is composed as follows:

- Only the **first** match is used.
- The first key, `[0]`, contains the **full first match**.
- The other keys contains the matched **groups** within the first match.

Example:

```
var string = 'abc_123_abd_456';
var regexp = /_([0-9])/; // Matches an underscore, and groups a number
var match = string.match(regexp);
// match[0] = _1 (full match)
// match[1] = 1  (group)
```

When the global flag is specified, the array consists of all full matches:

```
var string = 'abc_123_abd_456';
var regexp = /_([0-9])/g; // Matches an underscore, and groups a number, GLOBAL
var match = string.match(regexp);
// match[0] = _1 (first full match)
// match[1] = _4 (second full match)
```

I recommend to have a look at:

- MDN: [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Answer (score 3):

See RobW's answer for complete and accurate reference.

---

The [match](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp) method returns an array.

> The match() method searches for a match between a regular expression and a string, and returns the matches.
>   This method **returns an array of matches**, or null if no match is found.

The `[0]` is used to return only the first element.

Comment: ok thank you that makes sense, if you leave it off does it show every element in the array?

Comment: if you ahve it off, `var2` will be an array with all the matches yes

Comment: @DidierGhys **Terribly wrong**. When it's left off, only one match is shown, because the global flag is not specified.

Comment: @RobW. Indeed I read that from your documentation link. Am not an regex expert so I guess i've just learned something here. Sorry for the possible wrong piece of information !

Comment: Remove w3schools from your bookmarks, and use [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/) instead. Prefix your Google searches with mdn, and you will always get reliable information ([reasons not to use wschools](http://w3fools.com)).

Comment: I just tried writing the variable match from the above example (which has the array element number left off and I left the global flag off) and it does appear to return all values in the array... Am I missing something here?

Comment: Check the [answer from RobW](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9428633/123127). It is more correct and accurate than mine.

Comment: I did, and I tried this: function run() {
 var1 = 'abc_123_abd_456';
 var3 = /_([0-9])/;
 var2 = var1.match(var3);
 document.write(var2);
} it returns _1,1  i.e. the whole array

Comment: @user1230424 That's exactely written in my answer (first line: "match returns an array of strings" + example 1).

Comment: I'm confused then! Isn't this statement correct then? "if you have it off, var2 will be an array with all the matches yes " ? Sorry if I'm being a numpty!

Comment: @user1230424 "All matches" would be `_1` and `_4` (these phrases match the pattern). Your statement would be correct if you replace `all matches` with `the (full) first match`.

Answer (score 1):

When you need one single string, it's often practical to use `replace` rather than `match`:

```
 var1 = "www.asite.page.co.uk";
 var2 = '.' + var1.replace(/.+?(\w*\.\w*)$/, '$1'); // .co.uk
```

BTW, your expression doesn't look right to me. A better way to match TLD would be something like

```
(\.[a-z]+\.[a-z][a-z]|\.[a-z]{3,})$
```

which matches both '.co.uk' and '.com'. Example:

```
tld = "site.co.uk".replace(/.+?(\.[a-z]+\.[a-z][a-z]|\.[a-z]{3,})$/, '$1'); // .co.uk
tld = "yyy.com".replace(/.+?(\.[a-z]+\.[a-z][a-z]|\.[a-z]{3,})$/, '$1'); // .com
```

Comment: I didn't intend so much emphasis on that ;) Just a note: `.+?` should be `[\S\s]*?`, to be safe. When the TLD contains no prefix (`*?`), or when the string contains newlines (`[\S\s]`), there should still be a match. In this case, these circumstances may be unlikely, but generally, `[\S\s]` should be preferred over `.` (a dot does not match newlines).